# How do you expand a 3d model normal to its surface in MeshLab?

Tags: meshlab

I have some 3d models of various irregularly shaped objects, many of which include concavities. I would like to create "pockets" for them to sit into that are a little bit larger than the objects. (Let's say for example, the surface of the pocket is 0.5 mm away from the surface of the model.)
To do this, I need to expand the original model by 0.5 mm around every surface.
A simple scaling will not do, as the concavities create issues there. (The size of the concavity should be smaller after expansion, not bigger.)
About two years ago, I found a solution online that can be applied fairly easily on MeshLab, and it worked fine, but I have since lost it. Unfortunately, my attempts to search the internet have not been able to reproduce the solution.
Any help I can get on this issue would be most appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The *Uniform Mesh Resampling* filter in Meshlab can do this, run the filter with a positive offset to grow the model by that amount (e.g. 0.5 mm). The *Make Solid* tool in MeshMixer is similar, except it runs faster and gives nicer results IMO.